# Converting an add-rule to a service for firewalld

Tags: firewall, firewalld, multicast

I am having a hard time creating the following lines for multicasting into a service in firewalld.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=49152-65532/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p igmp -j ACCEPT
```

This is for a FOG Project server and [this is the tutorial](https://wiki.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php?title=CentOS_7) that I am following. So far this is what I have for the service and I am not sure if this is accurate.

```
<service>
  <short>Multicasting</short>
  <description>Multicasting for Imaging</description>
  <port port="49152-65532" protocol="udp"/>
  <protocol value="igmp"/>
</service>
```